# Are packetdrill tests portable?

Tags: c, linux, networking, tcp

Recently I had to write tests using the excellent google's packetdrill tool. (https://github.com/google/packetdrill)

To summarize, it's a tool that can test the TCP(or IP or UDP) stack of our computer just by writing some test cases that combines C commands, expected outbound and inbound packets.

But, I can't figure out how portable those tests are. For instance, if I run the tests on the github directory, nearly all of those fail.

Let's take this one `fr-4pkt-sack-linux.pkt`:

```
// Test fast retransmit with 4 packets outstanding, receiver sending SACKs.
// In this variant the receiver supports SACK.

// Establish a connection.
0   socket(..., SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP) = 3
+0  setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, [1], 4) = 0

+0  bind(3, ..., ...) = 0
+0  listen(3, 1) = 0

+0  < S 0:0(0) win 32792 <mss 1460,sackOK,nop,nop,nop,wscale 10>
+0  > S. 0:0(0) ack 1 <mss 1460>

+.1 < . 1:1(0) ack 1 win 257
+0  accept(3, ..., ...) = 4

// Send 1 data segment and get an ACK, so cwnd is now 4.
+0  write(4, ..., 1000) = 1000
+0  > P. 1:1001(1000) ack 1
```

I get the following error:

```
fr-4pkt-sack-linux.pkt:19: error handling packet: live packet field ipv4_total_length: expected: 1040 (0x410) vs actual: 297 (0x129)
script packet:  0.100283 P. 1:1001(1000) ack 1 
actual packet:  0.100277 P. 1:258(257) ack 1 win 29200
```

It seems to indicate that my computer (which is a 64bits Ubuntu gnome 16.04) sends only 257 bytes instead of 1000 for the first packet (the window scaling argument is simply ignored).

If I run other tests, such as `sack-shift-sacked-1-2-3-fack.pkt`, it seems to indicate that the wscale argument is ignored by my computer.

So, my questions are:

- Is that normal to ignore the wscale argument? Is my computer behaving strangely?
- If it's normal (like it's some specific linux TCP feature), how can we ensure that the packetdrill tests that run on my computer will run on some other computer?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was very simple but I'll keep this topic for those who are in the same situation.

In fact, I simply disabled TCP windows scaling via sysctl.

I used a configuration file here: http://cnp3book.info.ucl.ac.be/2nd/html/_downloads/sysctl-cnp3.conf

I changed variables with `sysctl -w variable` but I wasn't aware that those changes were persistent after rebooting computer.

So, don't make the same mistake as I've done: **be careful when using sysctl**, it can break your entire computer (if you forget to reset those settings after your tests).

After resetting to default, it now works perfectly. So, the portability of packetdrill tests seems ok (if there's no new major TCP feature).